# Flutter how to display a Future<List<dynamic>?> before filter it and reinitialize it clicking on suffix icon of search bar

Tags: flutter, list, searchbar, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm trying to display a list from an api but the list isn't displayed. I know where's the problem but don't know how to solve it.

I've tried to replace `allCandiesTypes = convertList(snapshot.data);` by `candyTypes = convertList(snapshot.data);` in the `FutureBuilder` & inside `ListView.builder`, if I do that, the list is displayed by default but the filter `searchCandyType` doesn't work.

After that I would like to reinitialize the default list when the user click on the suffix icon inside the search bar but actually, I don't know how to do it.

**CandyTypeSearchView**

```
class CandyTypeSearchView extends StatefulView<CandyCreationModel, CandyCreationViewModel> {
  final String? candyTypeName;
  static const String route = 'candytypeFilterSearch';

  CandyTypeSearchView({super.key, this.candyTypeName})
      : super(CandyCreationViewModel.provider);

  @override
  CandyTypeSearchViewState createState() => CandyTypeSearchViewState();
}

class CandyTypeSearchViewState extends ViewState<CandyCreationModel,
    CandyTypeSearchView, CandyCreationViewModel> {
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();

  List<CandyType> allCandiesTypes = [];
  List<CandyType> suggestions = [];
  List<CandyType> candyTypes = [];
  late Future<List<dynamic>?> _candyTypes;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _candyTypes = viewModel.displayCandyTypeList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget builder(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(
        backgroundColor: ThemeColor.primary,
        child: FilterSearchBar(
          filterType: context.translation.searchCandy,
          searchController: searchController,
          keyboard: TextInputType.text,
          onChanged: searchCandyType,
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: candyTypeList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget candyTypeList() => FutureBuilder(
    future: _candyTypes,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
          snapshot.hasData) {
        //candyTypes = convertList(snapshot.data);
        allCandiesTypes = convertList(snapshot.data);

        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: candyTypes.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final candyType = candyTypes[index];

              return Column(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    title: Padding(
                      padding: ThemeSize.paddingSymmetric(s, s),
                      child: Text(
                        candyType.type!.toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: ThemeColor.primary,
                          fontSize: ThemeSize.text(l),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Keyboard.sendFilterToFilterMenu(context, candyType.type!);
                    },
                  ),
                  const Divider(
                    height: 1,
                    color: ThemeColor.borderGrey,
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
        );
      }
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ||
          !snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Loader(
          loaderWidth: 30,
          loaderHeight: 30,
        );
      }
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return ErrorText(errorMessage: snapshot.hasError.toString());
      }
      return Container();
    },
  );

  List<CandyType> convertList(List<dynamic>? data) {
    List<CandyType> value = <CandyType>[];
    for (var element in data!) {
      value.add(CandyType.fromJson(element));
    }
    return value;
  }

  searchCandyType(String query) {
    suggestions = allCandiesTypes.where((candyType) {
      final candyTypeName =
      candyType.type!.toUpperCase().startsWith(query.toUpperCase());
      return candyTypeName;
    }).toList();
    setState(() => candyTypes = suggestions.isEmpty ? allCandiesTypes : suggestions);
  }
}
```

**FilterSearchBar**

```
class FilterSearchBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final String filterType;
  final TextEditingController searchController;
  final TextInputType keyboard;
  final ValueChanged<String>? onChanged;

  const FilterSearchBar({Key? key, required this.filterType,
    required this.searchController, required this.keyboard,
  this.onChanged,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FilterSearchBar> createState() => _FilterSearchBarState();
}

class _FilterSearchBarState extends State<FilterSearchBar> {

  bool showClearButton = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.searchController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        showClearButton = widget.searchController.text.isNotEmpty;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: widget.keyboard,
      controller: widget.searchController,
      onChanged: widget.onChanged,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90.0)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: ThemeColor.white,
            )
        ),
        prefixIcon: const Icon(
          Icons.search_rounded,
          color: ThemeColor.gray600,
        ),
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: ThemeColor.black,
          fontSize: ThemeSize.text(m),
          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        ),
        suffixIcon:
         showClearButton ? IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            clearSearchBar();
          },
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.close_outlined,
            color: ThemeColor.gray500,
          ),
        ) : null,
        filled: true,
        fillColor: ThemeColor.white,
        hintText: widget.filterType,
      ),
    );
  }

  clearSearchBar() {
      widget.searchController.clear();
  }
}
```

What am I missing

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved**

**FilterSearchBar**

```
class FilterSearchBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final String filterType;
  final TextEditingController searchController;
  final TextInputType keyboard;
  final ValueChanged<String>? onChanged;
  final Function(bool)? onClearClicked; //<----

  const FilterSearchBar({Key? key, required this.filterType,
    required this.searchController, required this.keyboard,
  this.onChanged, this.onClearClicked) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FilterSearchBar> createState() => _FilterSearchBarState();
}

class _FilterSearchBarState extends State<FilterSearchBar> {

  bool showClearButton = false;
  bool isClearButtonClicked = false; //<----

  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.searchController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        showClearButton = widget.searchController.text.isNotEmpty;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: widget.keyboard,
      controller: widget.searchController,
      onChanged: widget.onChanged,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90.0)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: ThemeColor.white,
            )
        ),
        prefixIcon: const Icon(
          Icons.search_rounded,
          color: ThemeColor.gray600,
        ),
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: ThemeColor.black,
          fontSize: ThemeSize.text(m),
          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        ),
        suffixIcon:
         showClearButton ? IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            clearSearchBar();
            setState((){}); //<----
          },
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.close_outlined,
            color: ThemeColor.gray500,
          ),
        ) : null,
        filled: true,
        fillColor: ThemeColor.white,
        hintText: widget.filterType,
      ),
    );
  }

  clearSearchBar() {
     widget.searchController.clear();
     toggleIsclearedButtonClicked(); //<----
  }

  toggleIsclearedButtonClicked() { //<----
    setState((){ isClearButtonClicked = !isClearButtonClicked; });
    widget.onClearClicked!(isClearButtonClicked!)
    Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
        isClearButtonClicked = false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**CandyTypeSearchView**

```
class CandyTypeSearchView extends StatefulView<CandyCreationModel, CandyCreationViewModel> {
  final String? candyTypeName;
  static const String route = 'candytypeFilterSearch';

  CandyTypeSearchView({super.key, this.candyTypeName})
      : super(CandyCreationViewModel.provider);

  @override
  CandyTypeSearchViewState createState() => CandyTypeSearchViewState();
}

class CandyTypeSearchViewState extends ViewState<CandyCreationModel,
    CandyTypeSearchView, CandyCreationViewModel> {
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();

  List<CandyType> allCandiesTypes = [];
  List<CandyType> suggestions = [];
  List<CandyType> candyTypes = [];
  late Future<List<dynamic>?> _candyTypes;
  bool isClicked = false; //<----

  @override
  void initState() {
    _candyTypes = viewModel.displayCandyTypeList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget builder(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    clearSuggestion(); //<----

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(
        backgroundColor: ThemeColor.primary,
        child: FilterSearchBar(
          filterType: context.translation.searchCandy,
          searchController: searchController,
          keyboard: TextInputType.text,
          onChanged: searchCandyType,
          onClearButtonClicked : (isClearButtonClicked) { //<----
            isClearClicked = isClearButtonClicked;
            setState(() {});
          }
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: candyTypeList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget candyTypeList() => FutureBuilder(
    future: _candyTypes,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
          snapshot.hasData) {
        
        allCandiesTypes = convertList(snapshot.data);
        suggestions.isEmpty ? candyTypes = allCandiesTypes : candyTypes = suggestions; //<----

        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: candyTypes.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final candyType = candyTypes[index];

              return Column(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    title: Padding(
                      padding: ThemeSize.paddingSymmetric(s, s),
                      child: Text(
                        candyType.type!.toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: ThemeColor.primary,
                          fontSize: ThemeSize.text(l),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Keyboard.sendFilterToFilterMenu(context, candyType.type!);
                    },
                  ),
                  const Divider(
                    height: 1,
                    color: ThemeColor.borderGrey,
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
        );
      }
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ||
          !snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Loader(
          loaderWidth: 30,
          loaderHeight: 30,
        );
      }
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return ErrorText(errorMessage: snapshot.hasError.toString());
      }
      return Container();
    },
  );

  List<CandyType> convertList(List<dynamic>? data) {
    List<CandyType> value = <CandyType>[];
    for (var element in data!) {
      value.add(CandyType.fromJson(element));
    }
    return value;
  }

  searchCandyType(String query) {
    suggestions = allCandiesTypes.where((candyType) {
      final candyTypeName =
      candyType.type!.toUpperCase().startsWith(query.toUpperCase());
      return candyTypeName;
    }).toList();
    setState(() => candyTypes = suggestions.isEmpty ? allCandiesTypes : suggestions);
  }

  clearSuggestion() { //<----
   if(isClearClicked == true) {
     suggestions = [];
     setState(() {});
     isClearClicked = false;
   }
}
```